Continue processing ItemAdd event after error when connection to Exchange server drops
I have Outlook VBA code waiting for mail to arrive in Groupmailbox.
It processes thousands of emails, then the connection to Exchange server drops, an error is triggered and processing stops.
I added to the sub hoping to skip the current email and continue processing.
On Error GoTo endProc
endProc:

This removes the error, but the VBA code terminates and I have to turn off and on Outlook to continue usual operations.
How can I convince Outlook to continue?
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Set objNS = Application.Session
    Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("GROUPMAILBOX\Inbox").Items
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
 
Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo endProc
    
    ~some VBA mumbojumbo
 
endProc:

End Sub

Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
      
    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function
    
GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
End Function


Have you tried initiate Namespace.SendAndReceive ?

Run Application_Startup manually. If olInboxItems_ItemAdd restarts, you can call Application_Startup after endProc:.

This looks promising to me, I have added manual call to error processing
endProc: Call Application_Startup  
unfortunately it did not helped. Thanks anyway

Put an Exit Sub just before endProc, the usual error handling process. Put a Debug.Print or MsgBox after endProc to prove an error generated in the code. If there is no error to handle, you can still manually run Application_Startup with F5 to reset the event.

Assuming a manual run F5 of Application_Startup resets the event handler there are methods to automatically run code independent of the failing event. Rerun Outlook VBA script 'Application_Startup' regularly

If the error is caught the error handler can trigger Application_Startup.
The intent is to reinitialize olInboxItems.
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim olFolder As folder
    
    folderPath = "GROUPMAILBOX\Inbox"
    Debug.Print "folderPath: " & folderPath
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olFolder = GetFolderPath(folderPath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not olFolder Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Found: " & folderPath
        Set olInboxItems = olFolder.Items
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not found: " & folderPath
    End If
        
End Sub


Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    On Error GoTo endProc
    
    Err.Raise 1
    
    Exit Sub
    
endProc:

    ' A handled error can trigger Application_Startup
    Debug.Print "Err.Number     : " & Err.Number
    Debug.Print "Err.Description: " & Err.Description
    Application_Startup
    
End Sub


Function GetFolderPath(ByVal folderPath As String) As folder

    ' https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/
    
    Dim oFolder As folder
    Dim foldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(folderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        folderPath = Right(folderPath, Len(folderPath) - 2)
    End If
    
    'Convert folderpath to array
    foldersArray = Split(folderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Session.Folders.Item(foldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(foldersArray, 1)
            Dim subFolders As Folders
            Set subFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = subFolders.Item(foldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function
    
GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
 
End Function

